# Import header of a word document into another one using Matlab

Tags: matlab, ms-word, ms-office

I need to copy the header and footer of word document into another using Matlab.

Until now I opened my word documents using actxserver:

`wrd = actxserver('word.application');
set(wrd,'Visible',1)
wrdDoc = wrd.Documents;
wrdFile1 = invoke(wrdDoc,'Open','D:\myDoc1.doc');
wrdFile2 = invoke(wrdDoc,'Open','D:\myDoc2.doc');`

I would like to copy the header and footer from myDoc1 into myDoc2.
In the header is also present an image.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that it might be easier - depending on your scenario - to save the document containing the headers and footers as a new document and then replace the body of that document.

Comment: The doc2 have more or less 50 pages with many tables and graphs and I would like to avoid a wrong formatting. However I can also try with your solution. How can I take the body of doc2 and paste it into doc1?